# SQL Server how to derive a column value

Tags: sql-server

I have a table like the following

```
  CaseId NewValue  Attibute   TimeStamp         
------ --------  --------   --------         
1      A         X          2020-01-01 13:01  
1      Au        WB         2020-01-01 13:02  
1      C         P          2020-01-01 13:03  
1      Ma        WB         2020-01-01 13:04  
1      C         D          2020-01-01 13:05  
2      Z         P          2020-05-01 15:20
2      Q         R          2020-05-01 15:21
2      Au        WB         2020-05-01 15:26
2      Ma        WB         2020-05-01 15:29
2      X         P          2020-05-01 15:31

Create Table #t1 (CaseId Int, NewValue  char(2),Attibute char(2),TimeStamp datetime)  

insert into #t1 values
(1,      'A',         'X'   ,       '2020-01-01 13:01'),
(1,      'Au',        'WB' ,        '2020-01-01 13:02'),   
(1 ,     'C'  ,       'P'   ,       '2020-01-01 13:03'),
(1 ,     'Ma',        'WB' ,        '2020-01-01 13:04'),
(1 ,     'C'   ,      'D',          '2020-01-01 13:05'), 
(1,      'D'  ,       'E',          '2020-01-01 13:04'),
(2 ,     'M'  ,       'P' ,         '2020-05-01 15:20'),
(2 ,     'X'  ,       'WB' ,        '2020-05-01 15:26'),
(2  ,    'Y' ,        'WB',         '2020-05-01 15:29'), 
(2  ,    'X'  ,       'P'  ,         '2020-05-01 15:31')
```

I need Output as follows

```
CaseId NewValue  Attibute   TimeStamp          NewColumn
------ --------  --------   --------           ---------
1      A         X          2020-01-01 13:01   null
1      Au        WB         2020-01-01 13:02   Au-WB  
1      C         P          2020-01-01 13:03   Au-WB
1      Ma        WB         2020-01-01 13:04   Ma-WB
1      C         D          2020-01-01 13:05   Ma-WB
2      Z         P          2020-05-01 15:20   null
2      Q         R          2020-05-01 15:21   null
2      Au        WB         2020-05-01 15:26   Au-WB
2      Ma        WB         2020-05-01 15:29   Ma-WB
2      X         P          2020-05-01 15:31   Ma-WB
```

Basically I need to Look for when Attribute has WB then concatenate Attibute and NewValue then populate the new column with same Attibute+NewValue  until either it find the new WB.

Again the process should repeat for new Case ids.

Comment: Can you please double check the sample data and the query that you have posted ? It does not matches

Answer (score 0):

based on your description and sample data that is not in-sync with result, it looks like this is what you wanted.

```
select  *, wb.NewColumn
from    #t1 t
        outer apply
        (
            select  top 1 x.NewValue + '-' + x.Attibute as NewColumn
            from    #t1 x
            where   x.CaseId    = t.CaseId
            and     x.TimeStamp <= t.TimeStamp
            and     x.Attibute  = 'WB'
            order by x.TimeStamp DESC
        ) wb
```

EDIT : change the `ORDER BY` to `ORDER BY DESC` to get the latest `NewValue` + `Attribute` value

Comment: Bro Thanks for the reply

Comment: Bro,Apologies for not giving correct data. I have corrected the table now. I need other WB also to be repeated.

Comment: The sample data that you posted still does not matches with the expected output

Answer (score 0):

```
 I have modified answer from Squirrel on above post and looks like this one is working.
```

`select  *, wb.NewColumn
from    #t1 t
        outer apply
        (
            select top 1 x.NewValue + '-' + x.Attibute as NewColumn
            from    #t1 x
            where   x.CaseId    = t.CaseId
            and     x.TimeStamp <= t.TimeStamp
            and     x.Attibute  = 'WB'
            order by x.TimeStamp desc
        ) wb`

Thanks for all the help!